# How to get $tag to fill into add_action() or add_filter()?

Tags: actions

I am a beginner with WordPress. Studying hook, add_action() and add_filer() and see in the documentation that

```
add_action( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )
```

But I dont know how to get $tag and where to get it to fill into add_action() or add_filter() function?
Thank you.

Comment: `$tag` is just a variable, nothing more. You can also think of it as "first argument passed to `add_action()`". So when the text references `$tag`, it means the first argument .. It often helps (me) to see the code examples where this is used, like `add_action('init', 'wpse_my_init_function');`, etc. Anyway, this is probably too broad/off topic for this plattform

Comment: Thank you. And in your example, it is 'init'. But how can I get 'init' value?
I mean I can find it it which file? or it is a function in somewhere?

Comment: You just set it, [there are many standard hooks/filters](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=list%20of%20wordpress%20hooks) and good plugins include them as well. I really recommend you read more up on WP (either in the doc or using a tutorial online)

Answer (score 1):

These 2 function `add_action()` and `add_filter()` are magics of WP and do not directly affect your code. In WordPress, they use `hooks` for mocking into existing functions, methods without changing it's code.

The `$tag` you are referring is the **name of the hook** that you want to use. List of core hooks can be found here https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks. However you can easily create for own hooks. E.g.:

- When you create a theme, and you want to allow others to add some additional HTML after your header, you may create this snippet:

in functions.php (or in you lib)

```
function get_custom_header($tag){
    get_header($tag);
    do_action('after_template_header', $tag); // Add $tag as param, this $tag is not
}
```

in index.php (in theme) or in any theme file

```
<?php get_custom_header(); // instead of get_header(); ?>
```

For hooking, others need to add this: (`$tag` you are asking is 'after_template_header' for this case)

```
add_action('after_template_header', 'hook_to_header', 10, 1); // 4th param tell WP to use 1 arguments, if you put it 0, you will not need to pass $tag to function
function hook_to_header($tag) {
    echo "After header with tag '$tag' text here";
}
```

Hope this can help you learning WP well my fellow. Good understand on hooks will help you to do advanced development on WP.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to replace your `$tag` in 
`add_action` function.

Actually the `$tag` can replace with [Hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/) ( terminology used by WordPress )
and in function `add_action()` they write general syntax and use tag instead of Hook. These hooks have Names which are String type and can be replaced according to your need.

Here is a Hook [after_header_theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_setup_theme/) which can be used as a tag in [add_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)
as

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','title_helper');
```

- `after_setup_theme` is a Hook provided by WordPress ( `$tag` according to function syntax )
- `title_helper` is custom function

Means upon setting up the theme `title_helper` function will call and you can fill `title_helper` function according to your need.